# IdentityServer4 Implicit Flow for Javascript Client without User Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a shopping cart application built using Javascript (ReactJS). The app will all listing products, adding them to cart and performing a checkout.

When a user arrives at the site, the APIs will be invoked by the Javascript client to obtain Product Listing, Categories etc. When someone clicks on a Product, the APIs will also provide Product details.

At no point do I require the User to log on to the system. I cannot also keep my API open. We are using IdentityServer4 to manage the APIs.

I can't use Client Credentials flow here (which is suited for Machine-to-Machine flows) because I can't keep secrets in Javascript.

I can't use Implicit Flow because it works on the principal of User Login, whereas I don't need the User to login at all.

What flow should I use? Is there a way to change the implicit flow to work without requiring a user login?

Would using an API Key be a better approach?

Any feedback would be awesome.

Comment: What are you trying to protect then, if no credential have to be provided? Just protect the methods that have to be protected with an user login and leave open the methods like getproducts and getproducts details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the implicit flow, it is literaly an user login flow.

I think you need to think about what you want to protect here.

You need to allow everybody ( anonymous) to call some methods: f.e. GetProduct.
You need to secure  the sensitive methods with login requirements like checkout.